# How can I pipe a string to a script when using subprocess.call without a shell

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using

```
subprocess.call(['prog', 'arg'], shell=False)
```

to execute prog and spare me to escape arg myself.

Now sometimes prog requires some input from STDIN. In the shell I can just use

```
echo 'some input' | prog arg
```

using a pipe. How can I do this with subprocess without escaping arg myself? Is this even possible?

Or is the only way to do this

```
subprocess.call('echo "%s" | prog "%s"' % ('some input', 'arg'), shell=True)
```

which isn't really safe at all.

Comment: Piping isn't really essential here; it's just that `echo` plus `|` is a little simpler than, e.g., a HEREDOC in `sh`. If you really want to pipe in Python, [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) tell you exactly how to do it, with a handy example. But you don't need it; just see Eevee's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['prog', 'arg'], shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate('some input')
```

This is basically what `call` does under the hood, except having the object around gives you a chance to call `communicate` on it.  (The return code is then in `proc.returncode`.)

Note that if you want to actually get stdout or stderr, you'll need to pass `PIPE` to the constructor for those as well.  As written above, they'll both come out as `None`.

[Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

---

**afterthought**: If you're doing a lot of external calls, you might also want to give [plumbum](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) a spin; it does a bunch of operator overloading hackery to provide syntax similar to that of a shell.

Comment: Good point about communicate over stdin.write.  Should have thought about the source of the question.

Comment: Thanks. This solution works great here and is sufficient, but plumbum looks interesting and will come in handy some time.